# Why doesn't Firestore use setters when converting from JSON-like data to POJO?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

This is with regards to the to and from conversion between the internal JSON-like representation of Firestore and POJOs.

From my experiments (haven't had time to read the code) it seems like when converting from POJO to JSON-like, Firestore code uses public getters.

However, when converting from JSON-like to POJO, Firestore code seems to be looking only at matching field names.

#### Why this is an issue

To maintain tags for an entity, the logical data structure to use is a `Set`, not a `List`. I can write:

```
private Set<String> tags = new HashedSet<>();

public ImmutableList<String> getTags() {
    ImmutableList.copyOf(this.tags);
}
```

This works fine when saving my POJO to Firestore, converting my (internal) set of tags to an array in Firestore.

However, when reading back this document into my POJO (`DocumentSnapshot.toObject()`), Firestore complains that arrays can only be deserialized to `List`, not any other type of `Collection`.

I tried adding:

```
private void setTags(List<String> tags) { //public method gives the same result
    this.tags.clear();
    this.tags.addAll(tags);
}
```

which should, in theory, have transparently allowed the conversion of the array in JSON-like data to my POJO, but this method never gets used. Instead, I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Collections are not supported, please use Lists instead (found in field 'tags')
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:524)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:280)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:178)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:714)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:674)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:503)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:242)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:234)
    at com.example.backend.data.FirestoreRepository.setId(FirestoreRepository.java:277)
    at com.example.backend.data.FirestoreRepository.get(FirestoreRepository.java:124)
    at com.example.backend.data.FirestoreRepository.get(FirestoreRepository.java:169)
    at com.example.backend.web.pojos.Test.getQuestionById(Test.java:129)
    ... 51 more
```

My current workaround is to have both a `List` and a `Set` internally, and then convert from `List` to `Set` after loading the data. It works, but is very cumbersome and error-prone (easy to make silly programming mistakes). Imagine having to do this little dance for 10 different entities & the possibility of inadvertent errors balloons.

Using Firebase Admin SDK version 6.3.0.

#### Some Test Code and a Test POJO

Here's a barebones POJO I tested again with:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

public class TestQ {

    private String id;

    private Set<String> topicTags = new TreeSet<>();

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public ImmutableList<String> getTopicTags() {
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(this.topicTags);
    }

    public TestQ setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public TestQ setTopicTags(List<String> topicTags) {
        this.topicTags.clear();
        this.topicTags.addAll(topicTags);
        return this;
    }

}
```

The test code that tries to create an instance of this class from Firestore document:

```
public void getTestQById(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, List<String> pathParts)
        throws IOException {
    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    DocumentSnapshot ds;
    try {
        ds = db().collection("questions").document(id).get().get();
        TestQ question = ds.toObject(TestQ.class);
        PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
        if (null != question) {
            question.setId(id);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | RuntimeException e) {
        log().log(Level.WARNING, "Unexpected error", e);
    }
}
```

Note that many of the properties of the Firestore document have been left out of the `TestQ` POJO. This shows up as warnings below:

```
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for approved found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for dateLastModified found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for dateCreated found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for level found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for options found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for approvedBy found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for text found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper deserialize
WARNING: No setter/field for lang found on class com.example.backend.model.questions.TestQ
Sep 18, 2018 10:19:06 AM com.example.backend.web.pojos.Test getTestQById
WARNING: Unexpected error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Collections are not supported, please use Lists instead (found in field 'topicTags')
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:524)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:280)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:178)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:714)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:674)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:503)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:242)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:96)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:234)
at com.example.backend.web.pojos.Test.getTestQById(Test.java:146)
```

The relevant part of the Firestore document looks like:

[image: topicTags property in Firestore document]

Comment: Why do your setters return something other than void?  That seems to also be a violation of the JavaBeans spec.

Comment: For chaining, to have a fluent client interface. Makes code calling these methods so much easier to write (e.g., `testQInstance.setId(id).setTopicTags(topicTagsListFromSomewhere)` etc.). Returning `void` or a reference to self (`this`) makes no difference to the outcome of `topicTags` setter (the method return type is not part of its signature).

Comment: What if you make the setters void, as expected for a POJO?

Comment: `public/private void setTopicTags(...)` works, but setting a non-void return type doesn't. Is this because Firestore library is using another library that sticks to the JavaBeans spec? Normally in reflection one only specifies the method name & parameter types to get a `Method` object. Are you guys also checking that the return type be `void`? Could you explain in your answer?

Comment: I can't really comment on the design decisions.  I suggest implementing a fluent builder/factory object for your beans instead of making the beans build themselves, which technically makes them no longer beans by spec.

Comment: A repository manages the beans, but instead of writing custom code for doing JSON-like to/from beans, am relying on `DocumentSnapshot.toObject` etc. in most cases. The code sample was written so that it was clear how I am using the Firestore library.